# DataGrid not updating when rebinding a new datasoure

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I bind an ObservableCollection CustomerList to a datagrid, it works fine when it is opened initially, but when I use a buttion to call the fuction to give a new object to CustomerList the datagrid is not refreshed, I am aware that this is the way how the datagrid update works, as the original CustomerList is not upadted, so what can I do to solve the problem in this case? I am using MVVM pattern

```
class CustomerViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList { get; set; }        

    public RelayCommand SearchCommand { get; set; }
    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(customerDAL.GetAllCustomers());
        SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchCustomersByKeyWords);
    }

    void SearchCustomersByKeyWords(object parameter)
    {            

        CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(customerDAL.SearchByKeywords(keyWords));

    }
}
```

Comment: You should add/ remove items from your ObservableCollection, don't reinitialize it.  The UI is connected to the original instance.

Comment: @GlennFerrie, yes, you are right, the problem is I do need a new collection due to the current design, is there anyway I can get the datagrid to connect to the new collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CustomerViewModel` is not actually a viewmodel. It's just a regular class. To be a proper viewmodel, it needs to [implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

When you change the value of `CustomerList`, you must raise the `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Otherwise, the UI will never know that the value of `CustomerList` has changed. The binding on `DataGrid.ItemsSource` has no idea that you updated the source property, so it isn't updating the target property.

`CustomerList` should look something like this:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList {
        get { return _customerList; }
        set {
            if (_customerList != value) {
                _customerList != value;
                //  Member of ViewModelBase that raises PropertyChanged
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CustomerList));
            }
        }
    }
```

And write a `ViewModelBase` class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`; you'll find many examples of that online.

A poor workaround would be to keep the collection you've got, but `Clear()` it and add the new items to it one by one in a loop.

Comment: I took your suggestion, it works fine right now, thanks!